# How to programmatically set COM+ Component -> Transactions to Not Supported?

Tags: windows, perl, vbscript, jscript, com+

I am looking for a solution to programmatically modify Com+ Component Property -> Transaction Support to “Not Supported”

The manual steps are the following:

1. Open `Component  Services` dialog (`comexp.msc`)
2. Expand `Component Services` -> `Computers` -> `My Computer`
3. Find and expand `COM+ QC Dead Letter Queue Listener`
4. Expand folder `Components` inside  the opened component
5. Find component `QC.DLQListener` and open context menu for this component and select properties
6. On the Properties screen, select “Transactions” tab and set `Transactions Support` to `Not Supported`
7. Click “OK” to Save the changes

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I spent several hours on this problem, I've finally got a solution on C#.

I've got a huge insight from the following articles:

- [Changin the transaction atribute using COMAdminCatalog](http://microsoft.public.platformsdk.complus-mts.narkive.com/VM99Lk6i/changin-the-transaction-atribute-using-comadmincatalog)
- [Retrieve settings from COM+ components via C#](http://www.jimmycollins.org/blog/?p=184)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using COMAdmin;

namespace SetComPlusTransactionsToNotRequired
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            COMAdminCatalog catalog;
            COMAdminCatalogCollection applications;

            // Get the catalog
            catalog = new COMAdminCatalog();

            // Get the list of all COM+ applications contained within this catalog
            applications = (COMAdminCatalogCollection)catalog.GetCollection("Applications");
            applications.Populate();

            foreach (COMAdminCatalogObject application in applications)
            {
                if (application.get_Value("Name") == "COM+ QC Dead Letter Queue Listener")
                {
                    COMAdminCatalogCollection components;
                    components = (COMAdminCatalogCollection)applications.GetCollection("Components", application.Key);
                    components.Populate();

                    foreach (COMAdminCatalogObject component in components)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Component: " + component.Name);
                        component.set_Value("Transaction", COMAdminTransactionOptions.COMAdminTransactionNone);
                    }
                    components.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```